# Java foreach and hasNext

Tags: java

I'm trying to loop through an ArrayList of Objects. For each Object, I want to call its toString() method and then join them with commas separating them.

I have some test code, but it's not performing like I would expect. The output I get for the following code is: `Adam, Bob, Catherine, Dylan,` When what I want is `Adam, Bob, Catherine, Dylan` (the last name shouldn't have a comma succeeding it.)

```
public static void main2 (){
    //ArrayList of Strings rather than Objects for simplicity
    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Adam", "Bob", "Catherine", "Dylan"));

    String output = new String();
    for (String str : test) {
        output += str.toString();
        output += test.iterator().hasNext() ? ", " : "";
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: `test.iterator()` returns an iterator the first element. It always has a next.

Comment: try to use test.lastIndexOf instead of hasNext as I suggested below

Comment: Another common way of handling this is to prepend the comma to each entry, except for the first.  Of course, that would either preclude use of foreach - you'd have to use a standard for construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Just use the iterator alone, instead of the 'for-each' loop
- Append a `,` only when the iterator has a next element

**Example:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> test = 
                new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                        "Adam", "Bob", "Catherine", "Dylan"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> stringIterator = test.iterator();
        while(stringIterator.hasNext()) {

            sb.append(stringIterator.next());

            if(stringIterator.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Adam, Bob, Catherine, Dylan
```

In the question, for the line

```
output += test.iterator().hasNext() ? ", " : "";
```

- `test.iterator()` returns an Iterator that *points to* the first element
- since there are 4 elements, `hasNext()` will always be true
- that explains why the output *is not as expected*
- Furthermore, an iterator alone is sufficient, no need to use both 'for-each' and iterator.

**Note:** It's good to use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for things like these. :)

Comment: Code looks like it'll work, but explaining the error is probably more helpful.

Comment: Sure, was about to add in why the original solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm very curious about the use of StringBuilder. I saw another post where they mentioned that the compiler would often convert Strings into StringBuilder or StringBuffer, making it equivalent. Is there some reason why it's better in this case?

Answer (score 3):

### Update

With Java8 you can use `String.Join()` with `ArrayList` of `Object`s.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<MyClass> test = new ArrayList();
    test.add(new MyClass("Adam", 12));
    test.add(new MyClass("Bob", 17));
    test.add(new MyClass("Catherine", 19));
    test.add(new MyClass("Dylan", 22));

    System.out.println(String.join(", ", test.stream().map(mc -> mc.Name).collect(Collectors.toList())));
}

public static class MyClass {
    public String Name;
    public int Age;

    public MyClass(String n, int a) {
        this.Name = n;
        this.Age = a;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Adam, Bob, Catherine, Dylan
```

### OLD ANSWER

Why don't you use `String.Join()`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> test = 
            new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                    "Adam", "Bob", "Catherine", "Dylan"));

    System.out.println(String.join(", ", test));
}
```

Results:

```
Adam, Bob, Catherine, Dylan
```

Comment: Would this work if it was an arraylist of objects, where you have to call toString for each item? the String arraylist is just for testing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ArrayList of Strings rather than Objects for simplicity
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Adam",
                "Bob", "Catherine", "Dylan"));
        int size = test.size();
        String output = new String();
        for (String str : test) {
            output += str.toString();
                output += test.lastIndexOf(str) < size - 1 ? ", " : "";
        }

        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one-liner

```
String.join(", ", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Adam", "Bob", "Catherine", "Dylan")));
```